# Why is my return value outside the if statement null?

Tags: java, android

I figured somebody would have already had this problem but none of the solutions out there are working for me. Here is the background. I am querying firestore to see if a certain index exists  in the document. If it does (hence the if statement below) then a field in the same document is returned. **EDIT: Working code at the bottom**

I have tried declaring the returned value to be global, local, final and nothing is working.

I am logging the results and where I check for "item image 1:" I get the url string I am looking for but when I check again for "item image 2:" the value is null. How can that be when the values are the same?

```
private String getImage(String classRestaurantId, final String menuItemName) {
        CollectionReference restaurantQuery = firebaseFirestore.collection("Restaurant_Data").document(classRestaurantId).collection("Menu_Card");
        restaurantQuery.get().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(QuerySnapshot queryDocumentSnapshots) {
                for (QueryDocumentSnapshot menuDocument : queryDocumentSnapshots) {
                    if (menuDocument.getString("menuItemName").equals(menuItemName)) {
                        orderItemImage = menuDocument.getString("menuItemImage");
                        Log.d(TAG, "item image 1:"+ orderItemImage);
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        Log.d(TAG, "item image 2:"+ orderItemImage);
        return orderItemImage;
    }
```

Here is my OnBindViewHolder:

```
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final MealPlanDetailsAdapter.MealPlanDetailsViewHolder mpDetailsViewHolder, final int position) {



        // Menu items
        mpDetailsViewHolder.mealplanMenuRecycler.setHasFixedSize(true);
        mpDetailsViewHolder.mealplanMenuRecycler.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(adapterContext, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false));

        String orderId = mealplanDetailsArrayList.get(position).getOrderDetails();

        FirebaseUser firebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
        if (firebaseUser != null) {
            for (UserInfo profile : firebaseUser.getProviderData()) {
                userId = profile.getUid();
            }
        }

        // Get order details
        final String restaurantId = mealplanDetailsArrayList.get(position).getRestaurantId();
        CollectionReference orderReference = firebaseFirestore.collection("Customer_Data").document(userId).collection("Meal_Plans").document(orderId).collection("Placed_Order");
        orderReference.get().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(QuerySnapshot queryDocumentSnapshots) {
                mealplanMenuArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
                for (QueryDocumentSnapshot orderDocument : queryDocumentSnapshots) {
                    // Get image
                    final String menuItemName = orderDocument.getString("menuItemName");


                    //String menuItemImage = getImage(restaurantId, menuItemName);

                    // Start of image collection
                    CollectionReference restaurantQuery = firebaseFirestore.collection("Restaurant_Data").document(restaurantId).collection("Menu_Card");
                    restaurantQuery.get().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(QuerySnapshot queryDocumentSnapshots) {
                            for (QueryDocumentSnapshot menuDocument : queryDocumentSnapshots) {
                                if (menuDocument.getString("menuItemName").equals(menuItemName)) {
                                    orderItemImage = menuDocument.getString("menuItemImage");
                                    Log.d(TAG, "item image 1:"+ orderItemImage);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    });
                    // End of image collection


                    MealplanMenu mealplanMenu = new MealplanMenu(menuItemName, orderDocument.getString("menuItemQuantity"),orderItemImage);
                    mealplanMenuArrayList.add(mealplanMenu);
                }
                mealplanMenuAdapter = new MealplanMenuAdapter(adapterContext, mealplanMenuArrayList);
                mpDetailsViewHolder.mealplanMenuRecycler.setAdapter(mealplanMenuAdapter);
            }
        });
    }
```

Here is the final, working code from ElektroWeak. I would be surprised if people are not looking for a similar solution to a nested recycler view where the data is queried from firestore.

```
final String restaurantId = mealplanDetailsArrayList.get(position).getRestaurantId();
        CollectionReference orderReference = firebaseFirestore.collection("Customer_Data").document(userId).collection("Meal_Plans").document(orderId).collection("Placed_Order");
        orderReference.get().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(QuerySnapshot queryDocumentSnapshots) {
                final ArrayList<MealplanMenu> mealplanMenuArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
                for (QueryDocumentSnapshot orderDocument : queryDocumentSnapshots) {
// Get image
                    final String menuItemName = orderDocument.getString("menuItemName");
                    final String menuItemQuantity = orderDocument.getString("menuItemQuantity");

//String menuItemImage = getImage(restaurantId, menuItemName);

                    CollectionReference restaurantQuery = firebaseFirestore.collection("Restaurant_Data").document(restaurantId).collection("Menu_Card");
                    restaurantQuery.get().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(QuerySnapshot queryDocumentSnapshots) {
                            for (QueryDocumentSnapshot menuDocument : queryDocumentSnapshots) {
                                if (menuDocument.getString("menuItemName").equals(menuItemName)) {
                                    String menuItemImage = menuDocument.getString("menuItemImage");
                                    Log.d(TAG, "item image 1:"+ orderItemImage);

                                    MealplanMenu mealplanMenu = new MealplanMenu(menuItemName, menuItemQuantity, menuItemImage);
                                    mealplanMenuArrayList.add(mealplanMenu);
                                }
                            }
                            mealplanMenuAdapter = new MealplanMenuAdapter(adapterContext, mealplanMenuArrayList);
                            mpDetailsViewHolder.mealplanMenuRecycler.setAdapter(mealplanMenuAdapter);
                        }

                    });

// Log.d(TAG, "item image 2:"+ orderItemImage);
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: you are missing basic programming concept. You can't return value from a callback like this.

Comment: I am not a professional developer and I have been coding for less than a year. I get what the others are saying but I am not sure how to implement it and I also dont know what the "step back" is supposed to be.

Comment: For example to start reading here : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html ... and then go to the top index of those tutorials, and decide with other basic topics you might want to "refresh". And hint: when you want to send a reply to a comment use @ username!

Comment: I tried using the @ but I can only @ 1 user at a time and the comment was for both of you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
restaurantQuery.get().addOnSuccessListener(...);
```

Here you are adding a listener to your query. This means `addOnSuccessListener` will return immediately, but `onSuccess` will be called later when the query executes in the background and returns a result. Therefore this code will be executed before `onSuccess` is called:

```
Log.d(TAG, "item image 2:"+ orderItemImage);
return orderItemImage;
```

which means `orderItemImage` is still `null` because it wasn't set by `onSuccess` method. You can place your code that depends on `orderItemImage` inside `onSuccess` method:

```
restaurantQuery.get().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(QuerySnapshot queryDocumentSnapshots) {
        for (QueryDocumentSnapshot menuDocument : queryDocumentSnapshots) {
            if (menuDocument.getString("menuItemName").equals(menuItemName)) {
                orderItemImage = menuDocument.getString("menuItemImage");
                Log.d(TAG, "item image 1:"+ orderItemImage);

                // Place your code here, or call methods that depend on orderItemImage
            }
        }
    }
});
```

**Edit:**

These two lines depend on `orderItemImage`,

```
MealplanMenu mealplanMenu = new MealplanMenu(menuItemName, orderDocument.getString("menuItemQuantity"),orderItemImage);
mealplanMenuArrayList.add(mealplanMenu);
```

so you can place them inside `onSuccess` for restaurant query and also move adapter creation code there

```
CollectionReference restaurantQuery = firebaseFirestore.collection("Restaurant_Data").document(restaurantId).collection("Menu_Card");
restaurantQuery.get().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(QuerySnapshot queryDocumentSnapshots) {
        for (QueryDocumentSnapshot menuDocument : queryDocumentSnapshots) {
            if (menuDocument.getString("menuItemName").equals(menuItemName)) {
                orderItemImage = menuDocument.getString("menuItemImage");
                Log.d(TAG, "item image 1:"+ orderItemImage);

                MealplanMenu mealplanMenu = new MealplanMenu(menuItemName, orderDocument.getString("menuItemQuantity"),orderItemImage);
                mealplanMenuArrayList.add(mealplanMenu);
            }
        }
        mealplanMenuAdapter = new MealplanMenuAdapter(adapterContext, mealplanMenuArrayList);    
        mpDetailsViewHolder.mealplanMenuRecycler.setAdapter(mealplanMenuAdapter);
    }
});
```

Comment: I cannot place the code in there because I am querying another firestore collection in the onCreate method not shown here. Hence, it is imperative that I call this method to obtain the string I mentioned.

Comment: The problem is that it may take some time before `onSuccess` is called, which means you would need to block the thread until it executes and that would result in a frozen and unresponsive UI (assuming you are calling this from UI thread). Can you post your `onCreate` method?

Comment: I added the onCreate. It is actually a OnBindViewHolder in a recycler view adapter.

Comment: P.S. I also appended the code to show what it would look like if I added the method to the main body.

Comment: No, unfortunately that does not work. As you can perhaps tell, I am using a nested recycler (horizontal inside a vertical) and depending on where I trigger the horizontal adapter, either the horizontal recycler is never called or all of the items for each horizontal adapter is repeated in every item inside the vertical recycler. This is why I wanted to use a method to keep the recycler/adapter setup separate from querying the image that I need.

Comment: Can you explain more what doesn't work? At first glance, it might be that `mealplanMenuArrayList` changes before you add the `mealplanMenu` to it. You should make the variable local.

Comment: Yes you hit the nail in the head, that is exactly the problem. Even if I turn it into a local variable, I still dont know where exactly I should define it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194663/discussion-between-electroweak-and-bvb09).